renderAS="pdf" not converting to hebrew language
im using renderAS="pdf" in my vf page, when it converts to pdf file it does work fine for english text, but the pdf is not converting to hebrew language. Is there a way to do it ? using renderAS="pdf" ?
i want to text to strat from Right to Left

Does this answer your question? Is my User is using an RTL language?

renderAs="pdf" has always been quite limited in what it can do unfortunately, wouldn't surprise me if this is one of the things it can't do

See if this Salesforce document helps as it has some limitations around  Right-to-Left Language
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.faq_getstart_rtl.htm&type=5
specifically - the doc asserts : Visualforce NO, PDF Generation NO

specifically - the doc asserts : Visualforce NO, PDF Generation NO

added Thanks @FelixvanHove
